# How do you debug/trace Google Cloud Messaging application

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to view GCM Registration IDs at the project level?
Is there a way to view requests and responses in the log file? Something along the lines of the tomcat log for the GCM?

Thank you!
--- chapkva

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-trace/) and [Google Cloud Loggin](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/)g. To see [logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer), use the Logs Viewer, open the Monitoring > Logs page of the Google Developers Console. Select the log you want to view in the drop-down menus, and type text in the search box to further restrict the selected log entries.

> Cloud Trace is a feature of the Google Cloud Platform that allows you
>   to view the RPCs (remote procedure calls) invoked by your App Engine
>   application and to view and analyze the time taken to complete each
>   RPC.

.

> Google Cloud Logging collects and stores logs from applications and
>   services on the Google Cloud Platform:

Comment: Verma, thank you for the answer. I must be missing something very obvious - when I click on Monitoring->Logs an empty page with an offer to read more about logs appears, but I don't see the logs.